# Работа с библиотекой GDI+ в delphi

Tags: gdi, delphi, библиотеки, gdi+

Подскажите, можно ли загрузить изображение из ресурсов с помощью GDI в delphi. (а если точнее, то средствами GDI+KOL)

Т.е. меня интересует как загрузить изображение из ресурсов без использования функций библиотеки Classes.

Вот пример:

```
procedure DrawPaint();
var
graphics : TGPGraphics;
  Image: TGPImage;
begin
graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(PaintBoxMy.Canvas.Handle);
  Image:= TGPImage.Create('C:\234.jpg');
  graphics.DrawImage(Image,0,0);
  Image.Free;
  graphics.Free;
end;
```

Как мне сюда `TGPImage.Create('C:\234.jpg')` подставить изображение из ресурса? (без функций `Classes`).

Comment: [тут нечто похожее](http://hashcode.ru/questions/245331/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-delphi-7)

Comment: и где там показано как из ресурсов изображение грузить? совсем не то )

Answer (score 2):

Думаю это будет выглядеть примерно так (стандартными средствами - просто GDI, потому что для такой простой задачи, как вывод картинки из ресурса GDI+ не нужен вовсе):

```
procedure DrawPaint();
var
   MyBmp: TBitmap;
begin
  MyBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    MyBmp.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'MY_BMP');
    Image1.Picture.Assign(MyBmp);
    //Canvas.Draw(10, 10, MyBmp); или так, если картинка должна быть на форме
  finally
    MyBmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```